# High pitched noise from Desktop PC interior

Tags: motherboard

I have a 2 year old home built PC with Gigabyte Z68 motherboard making an annoying high pitched noise.  I have tested all fans including CPU, power unit, and case fans as well as each drive and peripheral device in the box.  None are the source.  The sound begins approx. 10 seconds after startup and persists until shutdown. The source sounds like it is coming from the motherboard, but I can not identify what may be causing it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a "coil while" issue - This happens when the coils in parts of your computers vibrate when power goes through them and it can sometime whine depending on how stressed the coil is - This normally happens to your GPU, but can happen to a multiple of parts inside your computer as the electric current is going through everything.

If you have a GPU, try removing it and see if the whine goes away - If not, then the problem may be with your Motherboard/CPU. Best way to isolate this is to get a piece of cardboard and try to hold onto the coils that you hear the whine from - If it stops, then that is the effected part.

The main issue with coil whine is that you can't really get rid of it as it has to do with the physical component. Replacing said component is all that can really be done to get rid of the whine -

I have heard of cases where people will put silicone over the coil to reduce the vibrations, but I am not sure if this is really a viable solution.

Hopefully this helps a bit

Answer (score -1):

Although most of the forums suggest to disable C3/C6 state in windows to get rid of the noise and it works I found a far better solution. Go to your Bios settings and fix your CPU bus speed. (I have an AMD FX 4100 and it works on 200Mhz) Since you only fix your bus clock, windows will be able to change the multiplier and save you heat and energy but the high pitched noise gone forever (i'm drawing the conclusion that Bios Auto CPU bus speed is trying to manipulate with the default frequency but it cannot since its fixed and it causes some kind of problem to either the CPU or the motherboard )